# Selecting a Range using TableName & ColumnName in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vsto, office-interop, excel-interop

**What i want to do is to select a *Range* using TableName & ColumnName**

the Working Code in VB.net is

```
Dim xlApp As Interop.Excel.Application = GetObject(workbookName).Application
xlApp.Range(tableName & "[ColumnName]")._Default(i + 1).Value = 3
```

How Can i do just the Same in C# ??? i tried something like that but no luck :(

```
var xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlApp.Range[tableName + "[ColumnName]"][i+1].Value = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = 
     Interaction.GetObject(workbookName).Application;
xlApp.Range(tableName + "[ColumnName]")._Default(i + 1).Value = 3;
```

Try this

Comment: i tried your way: Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = Interaction.GetObject(workbookName).Application;

.Application is marked red in IntelliSense !